# Hosting single asp.net page with code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to host a single asp.net page which will have report viewer component in it and some code behind logic e.g. getting reports from SSRS.

What options do I have to host it ? Should I create a new web site in IIS just for hosting a single page ?

I'll be using this page to display it in a SharePoint web application in an IFRAME as I am having trouble with SharePoint application pages as they don't like report viewer component and I don't like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj77L6ThaLLAhXI0xQKHV7BDEEQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsvn.abisource.com%2Fabiword-testsuite%2Ftrunk%2Fimpexp%2Fdocx%2Fconfigure-rdlc-report-with-reportviewer.docx&usg=AFQjCNEhSAT6J27FHgwQ9DrJxNnYsTG1BA&sig2=zq9nT9xX6u9putiYbfknRQ&bvm=bv.115339255,d.d24) work around I found.

Comment: Based on your comments to the removed/previous answer below _"..can't put in Sharepoint application..."_, then doesn't that already point you to creating a new web site in IIS? Which you can use in an iframe as you wanted - the `src` address will point to that new resource in the new IIS site

Comment: @EdSF from my question - What options do I have to host it ? Should I create a new web site in IIS just for hosting a single page ?

Comment: How else would you host an "ASP.net page" that you've already determined will not work in your existing Sharepoint site? I'm not a Sharepoint dev at all so this is in context of ASP.net. There are other (likely more complicated) ways - like "creating a virtual application" (in the ASP.net context), though may take more effort

Comment: This is my question :) --- How else would you host an "ASP.net page" that you've already determined will not work in your existing Sharepoint site? , is my only option using iis host ?

Comment: An "Asp.net" page (one or more) is part of an Asp.net Web Application or Web Site. You've already determined that what you want can't be in your existing Sharepoint web application/site. Hence an _alternative_ is a separate application/web site (that you can iframe). I am of course, deferring to your Sharepoint expertise in pre-determiniing issues with [report component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522800.aspx) that made you look for alternatives. Might be stupid, but can't you just add a "stand alone" aspx page in Sharepoint? Again, I am Sharepoint ignorant.

Comment: In the Asp.net CMS applications I've come across, there are "CMS Pages" (with pre-existing depedencies) on the CMS application. But at the core, it's still an ASP.net application - which means I can add a "stand alone" ASP.Net page (or any Asp.net resource for that matter - generic handler, etc.) that does "its own thing" (whether or not it has any dependency on the CMS application).